# bootstrap icon not aligning in button

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-icons

My search button on the navbar has a bootstrap icon and text that are not aligning vertically

Fiddle link: [Fiddle](http://sfiddle.net/LetsHopeThisWorks/j39u7yto/)

html for the search:

```
            <form class="d-flex search-form">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">
                        <div class="nav-search">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search nav-svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
                    </svg>
                    Search
                </input>
                </button>
            </form>
```

css on the search that i've tried:

```
.nav-search {
   display: inline-block;
}

.search-form {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` with `align-items` to vertically align icons with text.

```css
.nav-search {
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}
```

```html
  <form class="d-flex search-form">
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">
      <div class="nav-search">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search nav-svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
        </svg>
        Search
      </div>
    </button>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter your viewBox attribute values to define the position and dimension in the user space. Here is the documentation for the same: [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)